# Have the physical properties of Kryptonite been discussed?

Tags: dc, superman, kryptonite

I am wondering if, for example, kryptonite is supposed to be to like radium or some other radioactive metal is to humans to Superman? Is it radioactive in a conventional sense? Does it decay, have a half-life? Or does it bear no resemblance to other elements? Is it even supposed to be an element or is it a compound? Does it melt? Of course, I am asking based on what has been disclosed in comics/novels/movies. It does not seem to me that any substance would affect a human as rapidly as kryptonite does, maybe some gas like fluorine would but not merely being in the presence of solid form of any element. I think a human could even hold Pu or radium for minutes or longer without noticing a problem.

Comment: `It does not seem to me that any substance would affect a human as rapidly as kryptonite does` ~> What superpowers of humans do you expect suppressed?

Comment: If Kryptonite does decay, like other radioactive materials, the half-life would be measured in centuries as it is still around to plague Superboy/Supergirl during their adventures with the 30th century Legion of Super Heroes.  I think I read once that, post Silver age, Lex Luther wore a ring with a Kryptonite stone, just to keep it handy.  Eventually it did affect him, causing loss of a hand.  Can't cite that one, though.  Oh, and it does melt.  I think it was during Supe's first battle with Metallo that he was able to do that.

Comment: @Bat: Not super power but vital processes -- kryptonite doesn't just suppress super powers, does it? It make Superman feel bad, sort of like, perhaps not coincidentally, radiation poisoning does humans, I think.

Comment: @Emsley Wyatt: Very interesting indeed! So is it possible that kryptonite emits conventional radiation? Like alpha particles or something? Was it discussed at all?

Comment: @Jeff - Things which are 15% plutonium generally emit radiation ;-) Within the comics it seems to be generally safe for humans to handle though

Comment: Citation for the melting part of my earlier comment. http://www.dialbforblog.com/archives/565/